# Hovering Across Sub-Nav Visibility

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a mega-menu like dropdown navigation in my React project. Since it's a functional component, I'm using `useState` to toggle the state and showing and hiding sub-nav that way.

The dropdown works, but the only issue is when the user hovers over the 'sub-menu', and tries to pan across to another 'sub-menu', it disappears. Any ideas on how I can keep 'sub-menu' visible as user pans across all sub-navs?

Here's the [codepen for reference](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/oNvxxwv)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for javascript to do that you can use a css :hover rule for that

You can do it like this

remove the `{isMenuOpen && (` rule that hides the subnav element

```
.subnav-block {
    display: none;
}

.nav:hover .subnav-block {
    display: block;
}
```

Not exactly what you asked for but does the job (in my opinion in a cleaner way)

Hope this helps.